# Adjusting Drupal views filter

Tags: views, entities

Can someone please help me to adjust views filter in Drupal.

I have content type with field collection and it is displayed through Field collection views module.
Also, I have a field collection ID filter to show some specifics FC. In this filter I have enabled "Remember the last selection" and URL argument for that. It works as expected.

For example, I have two nodes "node/12" and "node/24".
If I open node/12 with argument ?item=3, it shows node/12 with field collection #3.
However, after that I go to node/24 (the same content type) and it opens with field collection filter ID 3 (from node/12). However, it displays nothing, since FC #3 was created in node/12.

So it remembers field collection ID from node to node.
But how can I make it remember FC ID only with specific node. I don't need it to transfer FC ID from node to node (from node/12 to node/24, for example).
Every node has to remember its own field collection ID in the filter.